# Uploading a text file via POST method

Tags: vbscript

I've been working on this problem for about a month now.  I've seen dozens of web pages on the POST method and I just can't figure out how to use it.

I have this HTML form that posts data and a file up to a web site.  this HTML form works great:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample Post Request</title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="https://xxx.xxx.com//trackit/file/upload"
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <p>
            File Name<select name="name">
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select file name</option>
                <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
                <option value="Shipment">Shipment</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            File Date:<input type="text" name="date"> format : YYYYMMDD
        </p>

        <p>
            Upload File: <input type="file" name="file" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I'm trying to automate this so I don't have to use the form.   Here is what I have so far:

```
OPTION EXPLICIT
DIM sFile, sURL, sDate, sName, objStream

'File Type
sName = "Shipment"

'File Date YYYYMMDD
sDate = "20150717" 

' File we are uploading
sFile = "C:\shipment.txt"

sBoundary = "|-O-|"

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = adTypeText
objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile sFile


'Sending the data over HTTP Post
Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objHttp.Open "POST", "https://xxx.xxx.com//trackit/file/upload", False
objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + sBoundary 
objHttp.Send "name=" + sName
objHttp.Send "date=" + sDate
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So, what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to automate what the html form does with the vbscript, but i can't get it to work.   I'd like to make a fully automated process where I don't have to use the html form.  I just run the vbscript and everything is uploaded.   I know how to feed in the variables, I just can't get the meat of the script to upload the files and data fields.

Comment: A good first step would be to trace the request with something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) when you do the upload manually, so you can see the actual HTTP data. Also, you may want to be more specific about how *exactly* you "can't get it to work". Do you get an error? What is the status after sending the request? BTW, you can't `send` the request twice. You probably need to add name and date as headers, but that depends on what the actual request is supposed to look like.